# MySQL query to get sum of columns in a group of 5 rows

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions

I have no idea of a databases and SQL queries. I have a database table like this:

```
+-----+------------+---------------+-------------------------+
| id  | server_id  | secret_number | ts                      |
+-----+------------+---------------+-------------------------+
| 161 | R_SERVER   |             1 | 2023-06-22 15:04:09.549 |
| 162 | X_R_SERVER |            49 | 2023-06-22 15:04:10.570 |
| 163 | R_SERVER   |             2 | 2023-06-22 15:04:11.574 |
| 164 | X_R_SERVER |            48 | 2023-06-22 15:04:12.584 |
| 165 | R_SERVER   |             3 | 2023-06-22 15:04:13.588 |
| 166 | X_R_SERVER |            47 | 2023-06-22 15:04:14.602 |
| 167 | R_SERVER   |             4 | 2023-06-22 15:04:15.610 |
| 168 | X_R_SERVER |            46 | 2023-06-22 15:04:16.616 |
| 169 | R_SERVER   |             5 | 2023-06-22 15:04:17.628 |
| 170 | X_R_SERVER |            45 | 2023-06-22 15:04:18.637 |
| 171 | R_SERVER   |             6 | 2023-06-22 15:04:19.641 |
| 172 | X_R_SERVER |            44 | 2023-06-22 15:04:20.648 |
| 173 | R_SERVER   |             7 | 2023-06-22 15:04:21.658 |
| 174 | X_R_SERVER |            43 | 2023-06-22 15:04:22.669 |
| 175 | R_SERVER   |             8 | 2023-06-22 15:04:23.673 |
| 176 | X_R_SERVER |            42 | 2023-06-22 15:04:24.683 |
| 177 | R_SERVER   |             9 | 2023-06-22 15:04:25.685 |
| 178 | X_R_SERVER |            41 | 2023-06-22 15:04:26.690 |
| 179 | R_SERVER   |            10 | 2023-06-22 15:04:27.696 |
| 180 | X_R_SERVER |            40 | 2023-06-22 15:04:28.704 |
| 181 | R_SERVER   |            11 | 2023-06-22 15:04:29.713 |
| 182 | X_R_SERVER |            39 | 2023-06-22 15:04:30.724 |
| 183 | R_SERVER   |            12 | 2023-06-22 15:04:31.734 |
| 184 | X_R_SERVER |            38 | 2023-06-22 15:04:32.744 |
| 185 | R_SERVER   |            13 | 2023-06-22 15:04:33.754 |
| 186 | X_R_SERVER |            37 | 2023-06-22 15:04:34.762 |
+-----+------------+---------------+-------------------------+
```

The `id` field is an `AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY`. I am trying to write a query that will give me the `SUM` of `secret_number` for a given server, let's say `R_SERVER` in a group of 5 rows ordered by id. And when the number of left over rows are less than 5, those rows should be ignored. For example, the output should be like this:

```
server_id      sum
R_SERVER       15  (for ids 161, 163, 165, 167, 169)
               40  (for next 5 ids belonging to R_SERVER)
               0 or excluded (for the left over ids since they not yet 5)

X_R_SERVER     235 (for ids 162, 164, 166, 168, 170)
               210 (for next 5 ids belonging to X_R_SERVER)
               0 or excluded (for the left over ids since they not yet 5)
```

If it is difficult to fetch R_SERVER and X_R_SERVER details in a single query, 2 queries for each of them is also Ok.

Comment: If you "have no idea" you need to get a programmer to do this. SO is not a substitute for learning to program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query below uses the `row_number` function to create a series of incremented IDs for each series of `server_id`s. Then, the summing of `secret_number`s for each `server_id` is performed by grouping on an adjustment of that ID (aliased as `r`), produced by finding all prior occurrences of `0 ≡ r mod 5` (via a subquery):

```sql
with cte as (
   select row_number() over (partition by s.server_id order by s.server_id, s.id) r, s.* 
   from servers s
)
select t1.server_id, t1.s from (select t.server_id, t.k, 
   sum(t.secret_number) s, count(*) c 
   from (select c.r, c.id, c.server_id, c.secret_number, (select sum(c1.r < c.r and c1.r % 5 = 0) 
            from cte c1 where c1.server_id = c.server_id) k 
         from cte c order by c.server_id, c.id
) t group by t.server_id, t.k) t1 where t1.c = 5
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OwX7B49y)

Comment: Note that using `id mod 5` assumes that the IDs are consecutive with no gaps.

Comment: @Barmar The `id` being modded is actually produced from `row_number() over ...`, not the original ID in the table. In any case, thanks for pointing out the discrepancy, I adjusted the wording of the explanation

Comment: I'm still a MySQL 5.x guy, I haven't developed expertise in window functions, although I can recognize when they'll be useful.